# Node JS : Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I have looked at various answers on the site, but i don't seem to be able to find a solution.
I am making two almost identical requests from one page, one of them is made every 15 minutes and the other one is done on a click. The one that is called periodically is the first one to be called and the code is as follows:

#### periodic.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var assert = require('assert');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
if (err) {
  console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
} else {

  get_number(db,function(user_res){
    return res.json(user_res);
    db.close();
    })
   }
  });
});



  function get_number(db,cb)
  {
    var collection = db.collection('result');
    collection.aggregate(
       { $group: 
         { _id: {'number':'$number','name':'$name'}, total: { $sum: 1 } } 
       },
       { $sort : { total : -1 } },
        { $limit : 10 },
         function (err, res) {
         if (err) console.log(err);
         cb(res); 
      }
      );

  }

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is every time i call the second page, onclick event, then i get the data but then the error - "Can't set headers after they are sent" is displayed.

The code for the second page is as follows:

#### onclick.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var assert = require('assert');

router.get('/:number', function(req,res,next){

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
id = parseInt(req.params.number);
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {

      get_comments(db,function(user_res){
        res.json(user_res);
        db.close();
      })
    }
  });
});

var get_comments = function(db, callback) {
   var cursor = db.collection('result').find({ 'number': id });
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      callback(doc);
      if (doc != null) {
         callback(doc);
      } else {
         callback();
      }
   });
};

module.exports = router;
```

Both the pages are being called from one page only.
So, any suggestions as to where i might be going wrong.

Comment: You can't set them because the headers are sent as soon as ANY output is produced. Why? They are **headers**. They come at the *head* of the request/response! You can't change because it was already sent. How will you change a network package after it was sent but before it arrived? You can't!

Comment: @Ankit Please see my edit to the answer.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel what do you suggest then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in he `cursor.each` section. You are calling the callback for **every item** which in turn sends **individual response for all item** in the connection. But res.json can be used **only once for a request**. You must **restructure** your code either to send all data **at once** or send response using `res.write` and manually end the response after sending all data by caling `res.end()`

Try changing the `get_comments` to the following. You will have to edit the client that uses this data because it will be receiving an array of objects.

```
  var get_comments = function(db, callback) {
  var cursor = db.collection('GameScore').find({ 'number': id });
  var docArr = [];
  cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    if (doc != null) {
      docArr.push(doc);
    }
    cursor.hasNext().then(function(){
      callback(docArr);
    });
  });
};
```

In this case the docs returned from find query is iterated one by one and pushed to a temporary array. Then `curosr.hasNext()` checks if there is any more remaining objects in find query. Then the callback is called once with the entire array.

Comment: Ummm, i dunno why but this does not seem to work for me. The logic seems proper, but when i run it...it doesn't seem to do anything and in the end, it gave  - No response received error.

Comment: One more thing, if i put a console.log(doc) statement right after docArr.push(doc) it is printing the proper values, but then it doesn't seem to call callback function at all.

Comment: So, the function is getting stuck somewhere, because it has 8 records to return and it is printing the 8 records, but it doesn't go into the if(!cursor.hasNext()) loop !

Comment: @AnkitRanjan I don't know why but cursor.hasNext() is returning a promise for me, but the MongoDB says it returns a bool. When I resolved it using Promises, it worked. Now it works for me. See my edit.